# Where is the Report

Tags: wifi

So High Sierra has this great feature called

> Enable WiFi Logging

[image]

So I did (Option click on WiFi)

Now, where is that log report so I can see it ?

I think it is in `/var/tmp` but there are so many files there, so which one can I read to see the log.

Comment: When one clicks Enable Wi-Fi Logging from an option-click of the Wi-Fi menu extra icon, additional logging goes to the standard `/var/log/wifi.log` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [this article](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph25232?locale=en_US), Create Diagnostics Report will output to /var/tmp.  It takes a few min to finish running, and will automatically open a Finder window to the file when it's done, the filename will be of the form "Wireless Diagnostics_SERIALNUMBER_DATETIME.tar.gz"

The other option, *Enable Wifi Logging*, will more verbosely log to /var/log/wifi.log.  You can then view this with Console - in the sidebar select /var/log and then choose wifi.log in the next pane.  Clicking the Now button in the upper left toolbar will scroll lock the log you see the latest output.

Alternatively you can use Terminal to monitor new entries, for exampe with *tail*

```
tail -f /var/log/wifi.log
```

Be sure to disable logging when you're done as the file will quickly grow in size

Answer (score 1):

**/var/log/** is the standard location for log files in macOS. In this case we are looking for /var/log/wifi.log
Old versions are stored as wifi.log.0.bz2, wifi.log.1.bz2, etc

For viewing you can use the **Console.app** or **Terminal.app** with **less** or **cat**.

For reference, **/tmp** gets  cleared at shutdown so its not a good place for log files. LOL

Comment: ok, so which one (file name please) is the result of the Enable WiFi Logging

Comment: /var/log/wifi.log    See edit