# Possible to enable and disable wifi logging and creating diagnostic report from terminal command line?

Tags: terminal, network, wifi, automator, apple-diagnostics

Regarding these 3 options available from holding option key while clicking the wifi network icon:

[image: enable wifi logging, create diagnostics report, open wireless diagnostics]

I came across [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/316499/24632) for how to find and launch the Wireless Diagnostics option. I would like to know if there's also a way from the terminal / command line:

- to trigger enable (and later) disable wifi logging
- to trigger creating the diagnostics report

so that can script these actions in more automated unattended operation. I did also see a [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336197/where-is-the-report) for where to find the logs regarding the wifi logging, when enabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Guide to the output of the builtin airport command line utility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391815/guide-to-the-output-of-the-builtin-airport-command-line-utility)

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/382731/119271) as well as this [question/answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/284474/119271). That said, is there a specific problem you’re trying to solve?  Automating this (via script) is not how this is typically done.  To troubleshoot WiFi issues, you need to get the diagnostic info at the time of trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but those don't directly answer my question. I don't want to use airport, which I'm aware of. I want the CLI equivalents to the mentioned GUI dropdown options. I only know of the equivalent to opening wifi diagnostics app. I guess maybe Apple hasn't exposed those over CLI.

Comment: Yes, I know this automation is not standard, I'm helping build/augment a solution where we monitor user's wifi connectivity locally and on cloud side from stats reported by a local software agent. We want to be able to help user diagnose wifi issues before and while they complain, not after they contact us with a complaint. In this sense, want to utilize native OS diagnostics features but minimize (and not necessarily avoid) the user involvement in retrieving such info. The less we ask of user to help perform certain actions, the better.

Comment: There are not necessarily CLI equivalents to every GUI tool.   You can’t assume it just exists. As far as the log gos, its more of a report that gets saved to the desktop.  That said, what’s your expectation for how this “tool” will run?

Comment: The tool runs as a background service, and is not interacted with by the user except when a prompt comes up for user action, or if user interacts with what minimal GUI the tool provides in the system tray. This is much the behavior of software like antivirus, IT installed security tools installed on corporate enterprise computers, and software like Zscaler as an example.

Comment: The intent for the tool & this integration here is to avoid having to need user invoke those GUI options for us. We can invoke on their behalf (when possible), and they handle parts we can't do on their behalf. One being there's no way to bypass any Finder window popups on some commands, so user will be made aware of that. It streamlines the process, especially for less tech savvy users.

Comment: I'm aware not all GUI features have a CLI option. This post here was to find out if there are any CLI equivalents. Did my post not reflect that properly? I would ask Apple directly, but that's harder to do, especially without a paid developer account membership.